# Write a method to compute all permutations of a string of unique characters

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

When I test it with 5 elements set, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 2

Here is the code:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutation(ArrayList<Integer> set){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    if (set.size() <= 1) {
        permutations.add(set);
        return permutations;
    }

    for (int element : set){
        ArrayList<Integer> setcopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
        setcopy.addAll(set);
        setcopy.remove(element);
        add(permutations, element, permutation(setcopy));
    }       
    return permutations;
}

static void add(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutations, int element, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> setcopy){


    for (ArrayList<Integer> al : setcopy){
           ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           p.add(element);
           p.addAll(al);
           permutations.add(p);

     }

}
```

Comment: in which line ? please add full error data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `setcopy.remove(element)` will remove the int at position element.
You are not removing the element itself. If you want to remove the element you have to write `setcopy.remove(setcopy.indexOf(element))`

EDIT: you can also use setcopy.remove(element) but then you have to loop like this:

```
for (Integer element : set)
```

or you can do it like this:

```
for (int element : set){
    //copy
    setcopy.remove(new Integer(element));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There are two remove methods. 

E remove(int index)
boolean remove(Object o)